# Why does my code output 11 instead of 1 when I evaluate and output the value of the expression c = getchar() != EOF?

Tags: c, input

C Beginner here, I was experimenting with programming in C, and I expected this code to output '1' after every input, however it outputs '11'

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int c;
    
    while (c = getchar() != EOF) {
        printf("%d", c);
    }
}
```

Due to != having a higher precedence than = , I assumed that any value would cause 1 to be assigned to c, and after every input, the program would output '1', however it instead outputs '11'. I have noticed that when I hit enter without entering any input, it outputs '1'.

Comment: If your compiler isn't warning you about the reason, turn up the warning level till it does. `-Wall -Wextra` is a good start for gcc and clang.

Comment: It prints `1` two times because you entered one character and newline. Try to enter more than 1 character before pressing Enter.

Comment: @Shawn Author's expectation is correct: comparison is first, then assignment. The reason is because stdin is line-buffered, it reads two characters and prints `1` in two iterations, not number `11` in single iteration.